# Is this a bug for reputation on 'Top Answers' on my network page?

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page, account-suspension, sock-puppets

I was recently suspended on Stack Overflow for a sockpuppet account that I used to upvote my questions and answers. On my network profile, it shows my top answer as being worth 5 vote score, but on SO, it shows it as being 4 (due to the sockpuppet's votes being removed). Is it just not updating the vote score?

Links: [Sort array alphanumerically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55154863/sort-array-alphanumerically/55154885#55154885)

https://stackexchange.com/users/13597334/jodast

Screenshots: 
[image]
[image]

Comment: It happened to me once, but now i look at it and it is fixed, back to normal vote score, so maybe you just have to wait a while...

Comment: The script takes its own sweet time to run. Maybe check back in 6-8 weeks ;)

Comment: @CinCout actually as far as I know, it never runs by itself, even after 6-8 years. The network data is synchronized only as result of specific events, e.g. upvote/downvote.

Comment: I just gave him an upvote. That should do :P

Comment: @CinCout that fixed the bug lmao

Comment: @U9-Forward: In future, please use much more descriptive and accurate edit summaries. "Improved formatting" when you didn't touch formatting and did change several words is unhelpful.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Thanks, i am use to on Stackoverflow where i don't need a summary since i have more than 2k